# fetch access_token from the response and passing in Request Header of Rest Service

Tags: soapui

I have started using Soapui recently and i need an help.

I am able to fetch access_token from the response using Transfer Property.
[image: Transfer Property]

Now I need to use ‘access_token’ in the next request header as in the screenshot and how can I achieve this. (Need to automate passing access_token to the request header)

[image: Request Header]

I have done some research but i dint find anything on this part. Appreciate your response 
i am using SoapUI 5.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Property Expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/property-expansion.html).

Set the value of the header to `${Token#Response#$.token_type} ${Token#Response#$.access_token}`. This expands to the response of your "Token" step, and uses JSONPath to select the value of token_type (which is probably "bearer") and access_token.

Note that the Transfer Property step is not necessary, in this case.